# Can I create a dGrid without a domNode?

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have a tabular data structure that I need to publish to another dijit. But, that other dijit's topic expects a dGrid. Is it possible to create a dGrid "in memory", without any domNode? I'd like to copy my data to a dGrid and publish.

Comment: Thanks to the helpers on this question. I think the answer is "NO". I decided not to pass the dGrid. I modified the receiving widget to accept a different data structure. Going forward, I think that widget will also accept a Store. I also decided against creating a hidden dGrid, because that would be a large chunk of DOM, and I'd have to ensure that it was being cleaned up.

Answer (score -1):

Could you be more specific? If I understood your question, you want to attach a dgrid instance to a Dijit DOM node.

In that case, yes, you can create the grid "in memory". You just need to pass the Dijit DOM node **(dijit.domNode)** to the dgrid constructor parameters.

Comment: Actually, its the reverse. I want to create a dGrid, but NOT using a DOM node. I just want to create a dGrid in-memory, with column specifications, and a store. So, the dGrid  will never be visible.

Comment: Have you tried passing just the dgrid parameters and keeping the srcRefNode as undefined? I'm not sure, but maybe that will work.

Comment: @AJMorris This seems to be very strange requirement that you are passing a dgrid widget and not using its visual feature ( aka domNode). Normally you communicate between widgets by passing the data and not complete widgets. can you provide more light on what exactly are you trying to achieve. Any case if you do not want to use the domNode, you can pass a domNode whose display is set to None. i.e `dom-style.set("dgridDomNode", "display", "none");` dom-style is the `dojo/dom-style` module.

Comment: I agree with @frank. Seems like you need only the dstore, not the dgrid at all.

Comment: Sounds strange -- yes. But, this is an Export widget that exports a dGrid to CSV, Excel, etc. I could modify the Export widget to accept a store, but then I'd lose a lot of functionality (custom headers, formatting functions, etc).

Comment: @AJ Morris in that case, hiding the DOM node, like frank said, should work for your purposes